# Open presentation file in Keynote

Tags: ios, objective-c, keynote

Do you have any suggestions how can I open *.key Keynote09 file in Keynote application on iOS devices? I'm able to open presentations in embedded UIWebView control, but now I want to open it in external application as 'open with'.
I'll be grateful for any advices or hints how can I do it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this link
https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/samplecode/DocInteraction/Introduction/Intro.html

There are two ways to preview documents: one is to use UIDocumentInteractionController's preview API, the other is directly use QLPreviewController.